# New to Ubuntu cant upload images to directory for webpage through xampp worked fine on windows

Tags: php, permissions, upload, xampp, directory

Hi I'm new to Linux Ubuntu 18.04.
I have installed the xampp web server.
I have php code which works fine on windows environment with xampp. However i have now switched over to Linux and when i complete the page to upload an image to a directory it looks like the page completes processing but the directory itself is empty. Can anybody please help i have tried the permissions as other forum and videos have mentioned but this has made no difference.
I am new to Linux so please be patient with me

Thanks for your time

Kunal

Edit My code as said it may be slight cumbersome i'm learning php 
all database calls work fine.

```
<?php
     require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/ECommerce/core/init.php';
include 'includes/head.php';
include 'includes/navigation.php';
$dbpath='';
if(isset($_GET['add'])||isset($_GET['edit'])){
  $brandQuery = $db->query("SELECT * FROM brand ORDER BY brand");
  $parentQuery = $db->query("SELECT * FROM catergories WHERE parent =0 ORDER BY category");
  $title =((isset($_POST['title'])&& $_POST['title'] !='')?sanitize($_POST['title']):'');
  $brand =((isset($_POST['brand']) && !empty($_POST['brand']))?sanitize($_POST['brand']):'');
  $parent =((isset($_POST['parent']) && !empty($_POST['parent']))?sanitize($_POST['parent']):'');
  $category =((isset($_POST['child'])) && !empty($_POST['child'])?sanitize($_POST['child']):'');
  $price =((isset($_POST['price'])&& $_POST['price'] !='')?sanitize($_POST['price']):'');
  $list_price =((isset($_POST['list_price'])&& $_POST['list_price'] !='')?sanitize($_POST['list_price']):'');
  $description =((isset($_POST['description'])&& $_POST['description'] !='')?sanitize($_POST['description']):'');
  $available =((isset($_POST['available'])&& $_POST['available'] !='')?sanitize($_POST['available']):'');
  $size =((isset($_POST['size'])&& $_POST['size'] !='')?sanitize($_POST['size']):'');
  $saved_image='';

if(isset($_GET['edit'])){
  $edit_id = (int)$_GET['edit'];
  $productResults= $db->query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE id ='$edit_id'");
  $product = mysqli_fetch_assoc($productResults);
  if (isset($_GET['delete_image'])){
    $image_url = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$product['image'];echo $image_url;
    unlink($image_url);
    $db->query("UPDATE products SET image=''WHERE id ='$edit_id'");
    header('Location: products.php?edit='.$edit_id);
  }
  $category = ((isset($_POST['child']) && $_POST['child']!= '')?sanitize($_POST['child']):$product['categories']);
  $title = ((isset($_POST['title']) && $_POST['title']!='')?sanitize($_POST['title']):$product['title']);
  $brand = ((isset($_POST['brand']) && $_POST['brand']!='')?sanitize($_POST['brand']):$product['brand']);
  $parentQ = $db->query("SELECT * FROM catergories WHERE id ='$category'");
  $parentResult= mysqli_fetch_assoc($parentQ);
  $parent = ((isset($_POST['parent']) && $_POST['parent'] !='')?sanitize($_POST['parent']):$parentResult['parent']);
  $price = ((isset($_POST['price']) && $_POST['price']!='')?sanitize($_POST['price']):$product['price']);
  $list_price = ((isset($_POST['list_price']) && $_POST['list_price']!='')?sanitize($_POST['list_price']):$product['list_price']);
  $description = ((isset($_POST['description']) && $_POST['description']!='')?sanitize($_POST['description']):$product['description']);
  $available = ((isset($_POST['available']) && $_POST['available']!='')?sanitize($_POST['available']):$product['Available']);
  $size = ((isset($_POST['size']) && $_POST['size']!='')?sanitize($_POST['size']):$product['size']);
  $saved_image=(($product['image'] !='')?$product['image']:'');
  $dbpath=$saved_image;
}
if($_POST){

  $categories =sanitize($_POST['child']);
  $price =sanitize($_POST['price']);
  $list_price =sanitize($_POST['list_price']);
  $size =sanitize($_POST['size']);
  $description =sanitize($_POST['description']);
  $errors = array();
  $size= sanitize($_POST['size']);
  $dbPath='';
  $required = array('title','price','parent','child');
  $available = sanitize($_POST['available']);

foreach ($required as $field) {
  if($_POST[$field]== ''){
    $errors[] ='All fields With an Asterisk are required.';
    break;
  }
}
if(!empty($_FILES)) {
  var_dump ($_FILES);
  $photo=$_FILES['photo'];
  $name=$photo['name'];
  $nameArray = explode('.',$name);
  $fileExt = $nameArray[1];
  $mime = explode ('/',$photo['type']);
  $mimeType=$mime[0];
  $mimeExt =$mime[1];
  $tmpLoc=$photo['tmp_name'];
  $fileSize=$photo['size'];
  $allowed= array('png','jpg','JPEG','GIF');
  $uploadName = md5(microtime()).'.'.$fileExt;
  $uploadPath= '/ECommerce/stock/'.$uploadName;
  $dbpath ='/ECommerce/stock/'.$uploadName;
  if($mimeType !='image'){
    $errors[]='The File must be an image';
  }
  if(!in_array($fileExt,$allowed)){
    $errors[]='The file extenstion must be a PNG, JPG,JPEG or GIF.';
  }
  if($fileSize > 15000000){
    $errors[]='The file size must be under 15MB.';
  }
  if ($fileExt != $mimeExt && ($mimeExt ==='jpeg' && $fileExt !='jpg')){
    $errors[]='The File extension does not match the file';
  }
}
if(!empty($errors)){
  echo display_errors($errors);
}else{
  //upload file and insert into database
  move_uploaded_file($tmpLoc,$uploadPath);
  $insertSQL="INSERT INTO  products (`title`,`price`,`list_price`,`brand`,`categories`,`size`,`image`,`description`,`Available`)
  VALUES('$title','$price','$list_price','$brand','$category','$size','$dbpath','$description','$available')";
if(isset($_GET['edit'])){
  $insertSQL="UPDATE products SET title ='$title', price = '$price', list_price = '$list_price',
  brand='$brand', categories ='$category', size='$size' , Available='$available',image='$dbpath',description='$description' WHERE id='$edit_id'";
}

$db->query($insertSQL);
header('Location: products.php');
}
}

?>
<h2 class="text-center"><?=((isset($_GET['edit']))?'Edit A ':'Add A New');?>Product</h2><hr>
<form action="products.php?<?=((isset($_GET['edit']))?'edit='.$edit_id:'add=1');?>" method="POST" ENCTYPE="multipart/form-data">
  <div class="form-group col-md-3">
<label for="title">Title*:</label>
<input type="text" name="title"class="form-control" id="title" value="<?=$title;?>">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-3">
    <label for="brand">Brand:</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="brand" name="brand">
      <option value=""<?=(($brand =='')?' selected':'');?>></option>
      <?php while($b=mysqli_fetch_assoc($brandQuery)): ?>
        <option value="<?=$b['id'];?>"<?=(($brand == $b['id'])?' selected':'');?>><?=$b['brand'];?></option>
      <?php endwhile;?>
    </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
      <label for="parent">Parent Category*:</label>
      <select class="form-control" id="parent" name="parent">
        <option value=""<?=(($parent =='')?' selected':'');?>></option>
        <?php while($p= mysqli_fetch_assoc($parentQuery)): ?>
          <option value="<?=$p['id'];?>"<?=(($parent == $p['id'])?' selected':'');?>><?=$p['category'];?></option>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
      <label for="child">Child Category*:</label>
      <select id="child" name="child" class="form-control">
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
      <label for="price">Price*:</label>
      <input type="text" id="price" name="price" class="form-control" value="<?=$price;?>">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
      <label for="price">List Price*:</label>
      <input type="text" id="list_price" name="list_price" class="form-control" value="<?=$list_price;?>">
    </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-3">
    <label>Size*:</label>
    <input type="text" id="size" name="size" class="form-control" value="<?=$size;?>">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-3">
    <label>Available:</label>
    <input type="text" id="size" name="available" class="form-control" value="<?=$available;?>">
  </div>

<br>
  <div class="form-group col-md-6">
<?php if($saved_image !=''): ?>
  <div class="saved-image"><img src="<?=$saved_image;?>" alt="saved image"/><br>
    <a href = "products.php?delete_image=1&edit=<?=$edit_id;?>" class="text-danger"> Delete Image</a>
  </div>
<?php else: ?>
  <label for="photo">Product Photo:</label>
  <input type="file" name="photo" id="photo" class="form-control" accept="image/*" >
<?php endif;?>
</div>
<div class="form-group col-md-6">
  <label for="description">Description:</label>
  <textarea id="description" name="description" class="form-control" rows="6"><?=$description;?></textarea>
</div>
<div class="form-group pull-right">
<a href="products.php" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</a>
<input type="submit" value="<?=((isset($_GET['edit']))?'Edit  ':'Add ');?> Product" class="btn btn-success pull-left">

</div><div class ="clearfix"></div>
</form>

    </div>
      </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<?php }else{
$sql = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE deleted = 0";
$presults =$db->query($sql);
if (isset($_GET['featured'])){
  $id = (int)$_GET['id'];
  $featured = (int)$_GET['featured'];
  $featuredsql = "UPDATE products SET featured ='$featured' WHERE id='$id'";
  $db->query($featuredsql);
  header('Location: products.php');
}
 ?>
<h2 class="text-center">Products </h2>
<a href="products.php?add=1" class="btn btn-success pull-right" id="add-product-btn">Add Product</a><div class="clearfix"></div>
<hr>
<table class="table table-bordered table-condensed table-striped">
  <thead><th></th><th>Product</th><th>Price</th><th>Category</th><th>Featured</th><th>Sold</th></thead>
  <tbody>
    <?php while($product = mysqli_fetch_assoc($presults)):
        $childID= $product['categories'];
        $catsql="SELECT* FROM catergories WHERE id = '$childID'";
        $result=$db->query($catsql);
        $child= mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
        $parentID = $child['parent'];
        $psql="SELECT * FROM catergories WHERE id ='$parentID'";
        $presult=$db->query($psql);
        $parent= mysqli_fetch_assoc($presult);
        $category = $parent['category'].'-'.$child['category'];
      ?>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <a href="products.php?edit=<?=$product['id'];?>" class="btn btn-xs btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span> </a>
          <a href="products.php?delete=<?=$product['id'];?>" class="btn btn-xs btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> </a>
        </td>
        <td><?=$product['title'];?></td>
        <td><?=money($product['price']);?></td>
        <td><?=$category;?></td>
        <td><a href="products.php?featured=<?=(($product['featured']==0)?'1':'0')?>&id=<?=$product['id'];?>" class="btn btn-xs btn-default" >
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-<?=(($product['featured']==1)?'minus':'plus');?>"></span>
        </a>&nbsp <?=(($product['featured']== 1)?'Featured Product':'');?></td>

        <td>0</td>
      </tr>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
  </tbody>
</table>
 <?php
} include 'includes/footer.php';?>
<script>
jQuery('document').ready(function(){
get_child_options('<?=$category;?>');
});
</script>

 ?>
```

Comment: Add your code, what you have tried

Comment: The problem you are facing are read write problems that you xammp does not have. you can google the answer how to set that by yourself i think because you need to learn how to do that eventually. a linux distribution comes with it quirks sometimes so be prepared.

Comment: Follow this link https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: That's a lot of code. Can you reduce it to the minimal parts that are not working? Additionally, have you even tried to check for errors? Are you sure that the folder `/ECommerce/stock/` (which is on root level - pretty strange for a Ubuntu system) exists and is writable?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Chane

```
$uploadPath= '/ECommerce/stock/'.$uploadName;
```

to

```
$uploadPath=$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/ECommerce/stock/".$uploadName;
```

Comment: Just tried it in the terminal its made no difference.

Comment: A million thank you's you are amazing thank you so much  Kunal

Answer (score -1):

- Linux is case sensitive, have you specified paths correctly to match the case of the folders on the file system?
- Is the folder within your webroot - if not, you may have to edit the apache config to set apache permissions for accessing that folder (not just the folder permissions)
- Have you looked in the error.log to see what the error output is from PHP. Windows typically has display errors on, this might not be on for a Linux server by default so you'd be missing the error output.

Looking briefly at your code, though not knowing anything else like file name, folder name - you check for file extensions but have not lowercased all (input extension and array to compare with) to ensure case sensitivity is not an issue here. For example file.JPG and file.jpeg will not match your array.

Secondly youn don't check the result of move_uploaded_file, this might help to be sure it succeeded at this point, or not. As mentioned earlier, do check the error log.

Just to add, this code is full of security vulnerabilities - fine for starting out learning but I wouldn't go putting this into production anywhere.